# Throttle a Redux Saga that is being called from different actions

Tags: redux, saga

I have a saga that is being triggered by multiple actions. I want to throttle this saga.

From the documentation I know that this is the way to throttle a saga triggered from a single action:

```
yield throttle(100, action.REQUEST, requestSuggestSaga);
```

I am struggling to understand how to use this when I have 6 different actions that all call this saga. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your action types in an array like this:

```
yield throttle(100, [ACTION_1, ACTION_2, ACTION_3, ...], requestSuggestSaga);
```